# dplyr group by and creating a conditional statement with corresponding to the time variable

Tags: if-statement, dplyr, group-by, conditional-statements

I am using this code which is not giving me the correct outcome I need

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_product_code=if_else(any(product_code[date>max(date)-30]) %in%
                                    product_code[date<max(date)-30],1,0)) %>% 
  select(id,new_product_code)
```

to identify if an`id` has received any repeated `product_code` within the last month of its corresponding portion of data where the column `date` captures the time each `product_code` received by each  `id`.

this is a snapshot of the data

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
           product_code=c("178","321","252","147","178","321","252","147","178","322","253","698",
                  "411","322","253","670"),
           date=as.Date(c("2022-10-10","2022-10-10","2022-10-10","2022-10-10","2022-11-10","2022-11-10","2022-11-10",
                 "2022-11-10","2022-12-10","2022-12-10","2022-12-10","2022-12-10","2023-02-10",
                 "2023-02-10","2023-02-10","2023-02-10")) ) %>%
```

```
   id code       date
1   1  178 2022-10-10
2   1  178 2022-11-10
3   1  178 2022-12-10
4   1  411 2023-02-10
5   2  321 2022-10-10
6   2  321 2022-11-10
7   2  322 2022-12-10
8   2  322 2023-02-10
9   3  252 2022-10-10
10  3  252 2022-11-10
11  3  253 2022-12-10
12  3  253 2023-02-10
13  4  147 2022-10-10
14  4  147 2022-11-10
15  4  698 2022-12-10
16  4  670 2023-02-10
```

The goal is to create such a summary

```
id      new_product_code
1             1   
2             0
3             0  
4             1
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your description, but the following code works:

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(new_product_code = if_else(product_code[date > max(date) - 30] %in% product_code[date < max(date) - 30], 1 ,0)) %>% 
  select(id, new_product_code) %>%
  summarize(new_product_code = max(new_product_code))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am getting this error while I apply the code to the whole data: ```Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `new_product_code = if_else(...)`.
i In group 894: `id = 1353`.
Caused by error:
! `new_product_code` must be size 3 or 1, not 2```

Comment: Please can you share a small snippet of data which reproduces that error message using the code I shared?